# Android Timeout Exception

Tags: android

E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver$TimeoutException: Interrupted
at com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver.waitResult(SyncResultReceiver.java:60)
at com.android.internal.util.SyncResultReceiver.getIntResult(SyncResultReceiver.java:68)
at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.ensureServiceClientAddedIfNeededLocked(AutofillManager.java:1831)
at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEnteredLocked(AutofillManager.java:956)
at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEntered(AutofillManager.java:940)
at android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.notifyViewEntered(AutofillManager.java:897)
at android.view.View.notifyEnterOrExitForAutoFillIfNeeded(View.java:7838)

Simple text field in the layout, When I click on it, it throws this exception. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: Please add more details of your exception like what you are doing and add the code of the layout (textview) i.e. elaborate your problem so that we can understand better

Comment: Sorry I can't add the layout details..

Comment: without layout+java codes, it can't be understood why it's happening. You can research more about this exception in the google android docs here: https://developer.android.com/docs

Answer (score 0):

It only happening in Android 10. we have to disable autofill. android:importantForAutofill="noExcludeDescendants"